# How to post the same value from other options to the server

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, validation

In my React app I have a select box with different options. Two of these options has the same value to post to the server:

```
    <div className="form-group">
      <label>Category</label>
      <select className="form-control" onChange={this.handleCategorySelect} value={this.state.category}>
        <option></option>
        <option value="temperature">Temperature</option>
        <option value="humidity">Humidity</option>
        <option value="temperature">Water temperature</option>
        <option value="smoke">Smoke</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Problem 1: when I select a "Water temperature" option, I get a "Temperature" in an option field
Problem 2: how to make handleCategorySelect function working correctly? I mean, how to select "Water temperature" option with the same value as "Temperature" option and send it to the server?

handleCategorySelect:

```
  handleCategorySelect = e => {
    this.setState({ category: e.target.value })
  }
```

Problem 3: I want to disable "Frequency" form field when user select a "Water temperature" option in Category, how to do that? Any "if" statement inside or something?

```
    <div className="form-group">
      <label>Category</label>
      <select className="form-control" onChange={this.handleCategorySelect} value={this.state.category}>
        <option></option>
        <option value="temperature">Temperature</option>
        <option value="humidity">Humidity</option>
        <option value="temperature">Water temperature</option>
        <option value="smoke">Smoke</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div className="form-group">
      <label>Frequency</label>
      <select className="form-control" onChange={this.handleFrequency} value={this.state.frequency}>
        <option></option>
        <option value="seconds">Seconds</option>
        <option value="minutes">Minutes</option>
        <option value="hours">Hours</option>
        <option value="days">Days</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: I recommend using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select instead of this code. This works magically.

Comment: `Water temperature` will give the value `temperature`

Comment: I have checked. The water Temperature is working fine. Please change its value first.

Comment: I have edited my question, check it out guys if you can

Answer (score 0):

Both Temperature and Water Temperature has the same value "temperature"

```
  <option value="temperature">Temperature</option>
  <option value="temperature">Water temperature</option>
```

Change the Water Temperature value to something else

```
  <option value="waterTemperature">Water temperature</option>
```

Comment: I can't because server needs to get a value of "temperature" from both of this options

Comment: you are trying to disable the frequency if water temperature was selected, so before sending the data to the server disable the frequency div either by adding a class to it or removing it from the DOM, then set the category value to temperature. then send it to the server.